# Re-rendering same components in different parents with different content for them

Tags: reactjs, components, diff, react-dom

I'm a bit new to React, so any suggestion will be very welcome.

I'm working on this interface that has two modules at first: a Weather Forecast(Tempo) and a Slideshow(that I'm calling Wallpaper) that should replace infinitely one another based on an interval (I'll work on that later).

They both contain a few shared child components, with smaller changes on them.
When I switch back and forth between those two modules, does the ReactDOM re-renders all of it's children components or it diffs the code?

1st stage:

```
Stage1:

<div id="application">
    <Tempo/>
</div>
```

2nd stage:

```
Stage2:

<div id="application">
    <Wallpaper/>
</div>
```

Both `<Tempo/>` and `<Wallpaper/>` share:

```
@ = means I have different props for each module

<Header @/>
<Background imgName={"@.jpg"}/>
<Footer @/>
```

My screen flickers the background image and other elements when they switch. -_-' (I'm in a webpack dev server)

Thanks guys.

Comment: React probably re-renders most of the children. As long as DOM changed, there will be a re-render.

Comment: Yes. I've noticed that each time I replace a parent component on the DOM I get new ID's for them and their children. I can only conclude that there is no diff in that case. Only for props or state changes.

Comment: Have a look at the `key` prop https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children. I'm sure you can make use of that in order to reuse existing DOM.

Comment: So I rearranged them, so they'd become siblings. Each component would get a boolean active state that would change their behaviors.

@whitep4nther That `key` prop was indeed useful but in another case, where I had to deal with a component that was diffing in an undesired way. Thanks